# Vue google maps zoom automatically change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I work on project of someone else and missing one i thing !

This project is big so i just take the essential, is use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps and vuejs.

For use the module gmap is do that :

```
<gmap-map :center="mapCenter" :zoom="16" ref="gmap"
 :options="mapOptions" map-type-id="roadmap" class="gmap__map">
</gmap-map>
```

End after that a function do some parameters, but i keep it empty because that is my point :

```
this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then(map => {
 console.log(this.$refs.gmap.zoom)
 console.log(this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.zoom)
})
```

The result is 16 for the first, because is setup to 16 in component so logical !

> :zoom="16"

But the second change ! And it change correctly by the content displayed on map.
There is my problem, i search a lot, is didn't find why in this two step the zoom change and change correctly !

I don't know why, and the project is really big, so if you don't understand my question is simple.

If the default zoom is 16, who can it change ? (And it's not with map.setZoom())
The component have a automatically zoom change by this promise ($mapPromise) ?

Thanks a lot for you'r time !

Answer (score 0):

I fund that coderwall.com/p/hojgtq/auto-center-and-auto-zoom-a-google-map

And is just that : map.fitBounds(bounds);

So after a lot of hour the problem is cleard in five minute with this doc !
I hope it's help someone